# How to get multiply of 2 collections mongodb? (CROSS JOIN??)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 2 collections in mongodb

Clothes and Colors

```
Clothes:

[
  { "name": "t-shirt" }, 
  { "name": "pants" }
]

Colors:
[
  { "color": "yellow" }, 
  { "color": "red" }
]
```

I want to have multiply of 2 collections in result

```
[
   { "name": "t-shirt", "color": "red" }, 
   { "name": "t-shirt", "color": "yellow" },
   { "name": "pants", "color": "red" }, 
   { "name": "pants", "color": "yellow" }
]
```

How can I do this? Thx!

Answer (score -1):

Query

- lookup without any criteria (all with all)
- unwind
- project to fix the structure to get the expected output

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=63967e93424f6130d7f1217d)

```js
clothes.aggregate(
[{"$lookup": {"from": "Colors", "pipeline": [], "as": "results"}},
 {"$unwind": "$results"},
 {"$project": {"_id": 0, "name": 1, "color": "$results.color"}}])
```